# Sequelize Init restore deleted files

Tags: macos, sequelize.js, recover

I ran `sequelize init --force` command. And my models were deleted. How do I recover files from this command? They are not even in the trash bin... :( I tried to use CTRL+Z, but nothing works.
I am using macOS

Comment: If you don't use some kind of VCS then it is most likely impossible. Though there are special utils that can recover deleted files on macOS

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anatoly. I left possible restoration in the past. And retyped everything by myself :|